# How do I review suggested edits?

Tags: soporte, ediciones

I just noticed I'm now able to approve/reject suggested edits (by clicking on the `edit(0)` link on the edited question/answer). However, I can't figure out where the link is to see all suggested edits for review. Shouldn't it be under the `review` link at the top?

**Edit:** Here's what I see on the "Review" page. I'm using the latest Chrome on Linux.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I type this, I see that your reputation is just shy of 1,200. According to the [list of privileges](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits), you won't be able to see the suggested edit queue until you reach 1,500 reputation! So, give it some time and you'll be able to have this power. :D

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. It still seems strange to me that you can review suggested edits individually at 1000 but can't see the whole pending queue until 1500, but it does look like that's what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

You should go to Review, then chose the last tab on the right that should be "suggested edits". Is it there?

Comment: Note: I believe that tab only appears if there are edits pending approval.

Comment: @Flimzy I think it's there anyway; I checked my profile on Linguistics and I see the tab, even it's empty. If I click on it, there's a message "There are no pending suggested edits to review!" :D

Comment: The tab comes and goes for me... I don't see it now on SL&U, but I often do see it... *shrug*

Comment: I've never seen that tab. Do you get the tab at a later reputation level than the ability to review edits? In any case, seems like it shouldn't be coming and going... tagging this `bug` to see if SE mods have any input.

Comment: If you want to see your privileges, go to http://spanish.stackexchange.com/privileges and on the right, you'll see what you can and can't do and what user you are.

Comment: @Alenanno: It says I can edit anything, but I don't see the review link, which doesn't seem right.